# Blank screen when opening Photo Library from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I use WKWebview to open a page with some `<input type="file" />` in there. When selecting Photo Library and going in and out of folders, at some point the screen just shows white blank space, with just the navigation bar on top and it's reproducable. What happened?

I test this using iOS 11.

[image]

EDIT:

This is the initialization of WKWebView

```
let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jscript, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
    wkUController.addUserScript(userScript)
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.userContentController = wkUController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
```

Comment: `file` is file path of image which you selected from Library. Right?

Comment: what do you mean? `<input type="file" />` is HTML code

Comment: I suggest that you should show us some view controller's code and html example that is used

Comment: @OscarYuandinata I mean `file` is an url or something else?

Comment: @trungduc `file` is an input type.

@DJ-Glock the html involved is just that. an input element. I added the WKWebView initialization in edit